# Play JSON Reads: read value which can be presented in multiple types

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I has such JSON for `ship`:

```
{
  "name" : "Watership Elizbeth",
  "sea": "white",
  "size": 100500,
  "residents" : [ {
    "type" : "men",
    "age" : 4,
    "sex": 0
  }, {
    "type" : "cat",
    "legs" :4,
    "color" : "black",
    "leg1" :{
      "color" : "black"
    },
    "leg2" :{
      "color" : "white"
    },
    "leg3" :{
      "color" : "brown"
    },
    "leg4" :{
      "color" : "black"
    }
  },{
    "type" : "bird",
    "size" : "XXL",
    "name": "ostrich"
  }, {"type": "water",...}, {"type": "mice",...}, {...}]
}
```

As you see in JsArray `residents` i has residents which is different:`men`, `cat`, `bird`, ...`water`,... All that residents of `ship` has own simple case classes in Scala code:

```
case class Men (type: String, age: Int, sex: Int)
case class Leg (color: String)
case class Cat (type: String, legs: Int, color: String, leg1: Leg, leg2: Leg, leg3: Leg, leg4: Leg)
case class Bird (...)
```

Also for each simple case class i write `readers` in their companion objects:

```
object Men {
implicit val reads: Reads[Ship] = (
    (JsPath \ "type").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "age").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "sex").read[Int]
    )(Ship.apply _)
}
// and so on for another objects...
```

The main problem that i do not find how to create case class for `Ship` and its `reads`:

```
case class Ship (name: String, sea: String, size: Int, residents: Seq[???])

object Ship {
implicit val reads: Reads[Ship] = (
    (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "sea").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "size").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "residents").read[Seq[???]]
    )(Ship.apply _)
}
```

As you see `residents` is array which elements can be different types: `Men`, `Cat`, `Bird`.. I want instead `???` put in reads of `Ship` all objects of my types or some like `AnyVal, but it is not work:

```
// for case classes
case class Ship (name: String, sea: String, size: Int, residents: Seq[Man,Cat,Bird,...])
case class Ship (name: String, sea: String, size: Int, residents: Seq[AnyVal])

// for case reads
(JsPath \ "residents").read[Seq[Man,Cat,Bird,...]]
(JsPath \ "residents").read[Seq[AnyVal]]
```

How to write case class `Ship` and its `reads` which can read in its key multiple types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to extend all case classes from a sealed trait. That way play-json can generate a Reads automatically:

```
sealed trait Resident

case class Men (age: Int, sex: Int) extends Resident
case class Leg (color: String) extends Resident
case class Cat (legs: Int, color: String, leg1: Leg, leg2: Leg, leg3: Leg, leg4: Leg) extends Resident
case class Bird (...) extends Resident

object Resident {
  private val cfg = JsonConfiguration(
      discriminator = "type",

      typeNaming = JsonNaming { fullName =>
        fullName
          .replaceFirst(".*[.]", "")
          .toLowerCase
      }
    )

  implicit val reads = Json.configured(cfg).reads[Resident]
}

case class Ship (name: String, sea: String, size: Int, residents: Seq[Resident])

object Ship {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Ship] = Json.reads[Ship]
}
```

---

[Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/avdv/RAVlqwTkSlmnnFzBbX56ew/3) is a complete example.